# AngularJS - $templateCache is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

I am trying to load a template file in an AngularStrap popover, however I am having trouble using $templateCache. I seem to be a step further back than the other SO questions, hence this seemingly double one.

Following the API docs I added a `<script type="text/ng-template" id="popoverTemplate.html"></script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag. When I use `<div ng-include="'popoverTemplate.html'"></div>` on my page, I get nothing. If I try using `console.log($templateCache.get("popoverTemplate.html"))` I get "$templateCache is not defined", which leads me to assume I am missing a crucial step. However, I can't find how to do it in the docs or other SO questions.

EDIT:
Injecting the service was the missing link. However, when I inject the service, the controller's other function no longer works, but if you inject al the function's parameters the working code becomes:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app").controller("managerController", ["$scope", "imageHierarchyRepository", "$templateCache", function ($scope, imageHierarchyRepository, $templateCache) {
        imageHierarchyRepository.query(function(data) {
            $scope.hierarchies = data;
        });

        var template = $templateCache.get("popoverTemplate.html");
        console.log(template);
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: You have to inject the service where you want to use it. `function ($templateCache)`. And the script template must be inside the angular appication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the template script tag . You have to insert it inside the angular application. That is inside the element with the `ng-app` attribute or the element used to bootstrap the app if you don't use the `ng-app` tag.

```
<body ng-app="myapp">

  <div ng-template="'myTemplate.html'"></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
    // whate ever
  </script>
</body>
```

If you want to retrieve the template on a component of the application then you need to inject the service where you want to consume it:

```
controller('FooCtrl', ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
  var template = $templateCache.get('myTemplate.html');
}]);
```

Or

```
controller('FooCtlr', FooCtrl);

FooCtrl ($templateCache) {};

FooCtrl.$inject = ['$templateCache'];
```

**EDIT**

Do not register two controllers with the same name because then you override the first one with the last one.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app").controller("managerController",["$scope", "imageHierarchyRepository", "$templateCache", function ($scope, imageHierarchyRepository, $templateCache) {
        var template = $templateCache.get("popoverTemplate.html");
        console.log(template);
        imageHierarchyRepository.query(function(data) {
            $scope.hierarchies = data;
        });
    }]);


})();
```

Comment: everything is within my `<body ng-app="app">` tags. Injecting the service ruins the rest of the controller, but it does pass the template (I can see it in the console). I have added the controller code to the question, could you explain how I should set up the service injection, without destroying the rest of the controller?

Comment: You are overriding the first controller with the last controller

Comment: if I combine them the first controller no longer works. Should I make a new controller just loading the template? Or can I combine them and I just don't know how?

Comment: found it, didn't know you have to inject all the function's parameters, but when I do it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Small addition**: Although there are few ways to achieve your goals, like wrapping your whole HTML in `<script>` tags and all that, the best approach for me was to add the `$templateCache` logic into each Angular directive. This way, I could avoid using any external packages like `grunt angular-templates` (which is excellent but overkill for my app).

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.directive('MyDirective', ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: $templateCache.get('MyTemplate').data,
        controller: 'MyController',
        controllerAs: 'MyController'
    };
}]).run(function($templateCache, $http) {
    $http.get('templates/MyTemplate.html').then(function(response) {
        $templateCache.put('MyTemplate', response);
    })
});
```

Hope this helps!